# Creating Dialog in a Fragment, and from Dialog creating dialogfragment, and want to access TextView of Dialog in dialogFragment

Tags: android

I have created a Custom Dialog in DiscussionFragment. Dialog is Successfully working.

```
//Dialog in Fragment Class
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.create_post_layout);
                dialog.setTitle("Post");
```

I am calling a TimePickerFragment from dialog's Button OnClick which is successfully opening.

```
setTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "create_post_layout");
                            //(getFragmentManager(),"post_layout");
                        }
                    });
```

Now i want to access TextView of Dialog in TimePickerFragment Class like this,

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        //Do something with the user chosen time
        //Get reference of host activity (XML Layout File) TextView widget

        View dialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_post_layout, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.postTimeTV);
        tv.setText("String");
        String min = String.valueOf(minute);
```

**setText is not working returning E/textview: initAddtionalStyle default**
**no NullPointerException**

For Just Activity not Dialog i can access TextView as follows in OnTimeSet

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.postTimeTV);
        tv.setText("String");
        String min = String.valueOf(minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post more code of TimePickerFragment for better answers.

As far as i can see you'r inflating a layoutfile in onTimeSet() without using it as content view for your Dialog. 
Then you get the TextView of this new inflated view wich is not the Dialog's view.

I would access the Textview in DialogFragments onCreateDialog() to ensure you use the correct View and save it in a global variable. 
Like:

```
private TextView tv;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(){
   ....
   tv = (TextView) ... findById(...)
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
   tv.setText(...);
}
```

Comment: Actually TimePickerFragment does not creating dialog in which textview is located. then why i should call onCreateDialog

Comment: i think i got u wrong ... You create a regular Dialog with a Button to open the TimePickerFragmentDialog and after that you want to Display the Time in the regular Dialog?